# Creating a chat (client) program. How can I add simultaneous conversation?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
# nao tem servidor UDP no google -> vamos usar netcat como servidor UDP!
#Programa de chat: so fala um de cada vez
#implementar falando ao mesmo tempo

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


"""
pacotes_recebidos = client.recvfrom(1024) devolve uma tupla:
(' llallalaaaa\n', ('192.168.1.4', 667))

msg recebida + (IP,porta)
"""
try:

    while 1: #while True
        client.sendto(input("Voce: ") +"\n", ("192.168.1.4", 668))  # endereço do servidor UDP do kali linux usando netcat
        msg, friend = client.recvfrom(1024)
        print(str(friend) + ": " + msg)
 #se quiser apenas o ip: use friend[0]
# convertemos str(friend) porque recebemos o erro:
# (TypeError(can only concatenate tuple (not str) to tuple,))

    client.close()


except Exception as erro:
    print("Conexao falhou ")
    print("O erro foi: ", erro)
    client.close()
```

In python 3.5 (Linux), when I sent "hi" this code shows error:

```
('O erro foi: ', NameError("name 'hi' is not defined",))
```

The code run on python 2.7.

I would like to make two people can talk simultaneously , how do? At the moment , only one person at a time can enter the message we have to wait for one of the participants write and hit to continue Could someone help me?
I use netcat as server.

Comment: You'll need a server script that accepts socket connections and when a message is received from a client, relays that message to all clients.

Comment: I am using netcat as server!

Comment: `msg, friend = client.recvfrom(1024)` blocks the loop from executing until more data is received, what you should do is have 2 threads, one from receiving data and one for sending data. I can give you an example, but it would have to be in python 3

Comment: @XanderLuciano, I appraciate your help. Could u give me a thread example on python 3?

Comment: @XanderLuciano, What about the error on python 3? when I sent "hi" this code shows error:

('O erro foi: ', NameError("name 'hi' is not defined",))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a 'multithreaded' UDP python client in python3 that allows messages to be sent and received simultaneously.

I personally like to make a Wrapper for the `socket` class that has all the threading and functions built in, so we'll start with the wrapper.

```
import socket
import threading

class socketwrapper:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.server = (host, port)
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.client.settimeout(5) # Time is in seconds
        self.connected = False

    def startrecvdata(self):
        recvThread = threading.Thread(target=self.recvdata)
        recvThread.daemon = True
        recvThread.start()
        self.connected = True

    def recvdata(self):
        while self.connected:
            try:
                data, friend = self.client.recvfrom(1024)
                if data:
                    print(str(friend) + ": " + data.decode('utf-8'))
            except socket.timeout:
                else:
                    print("No Message Received before timeout.")
                    continue
            except:
                self.connected = False
        self.stop()

    def sendmessage(self, data):
        data += "\n"
        self.client.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), self.server)

    def stop(self):
        self.client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        self.client.close()
```

So as you can see we have a couple functions in this, the two you should notice are `startrecvdata(self)` and `recvdata(self)`. We will call the `startrecvdata(self)` from our main function, which will start the `recvdata(self)` thread. That function will print any received data to the console.

Additionally, notice that we have `settimeout(5)` in the `__init__` function of the wrapper, which sets a 5 second timeout on the socket connection. This way, we can close the entire program cleanly, shutting down and closing the socket with the `stop()` function.

Now for the main loop. Since we setup all of our functions in the wrapper class, we can have a super simple and clean loop:

```
def main():
    server = socketwrapper('192.168.1.1', 30000)
    server.startrecvdata()

    while not server.connected:
        continue

    print("Connected to server! Type 'exit' to quit.")

    while server.connected:
        message = input("Voce: ")
        if message == "exit":
            server.connected = False
            break

        server.sendmessage(message)

    server.stop()
```

In this loop, we create a an instance of our `socketwrapper` which initializes everything for us. Then we call `server.startrecvdata()` which, as we said above, starts the function to receive and print data from the UDP connection. The `while not server.connected` blocks the program until the thread has started.

Lastly, we have our `while server.connected` loop, which waits for user input in the console. We check if the user wants to exit, and if they do, we set `server.connected = False` and `break` our while loop.
If the user does not want to exit, we send the message to the UDP server.

After the loop ends, we call `server.stop` to ensure that the socket is closed before exiting the application.

Comment: I changed on my code client.sendto(input("Voce: ") + "\n", ("192.168.1.4", 668)) to  client.sendto (bytes(input("Voce: "),'ut‌​f-8') + bytes("\n",'ut‌​f-8'‌​), bytes(("192.168.1.4"‌​, 668),'utf-8')) . O erro foi: unknown encoding: ut‌​f-8

Comment: I tried:         client.sendto (bytes(input("Voce: ")).encode('utf8') + bytes("\n").encode('utf8'), bytes(("192.168.1.4", 668)).encode('utf8')) -> O erro foi:  string argument without an encoding

Comment: no no, just do `client.sendto ((input("Voce: ")).encode('utf8') + ("\n").encode('‌​utf8'), self.server)` like I had in my answer. See my edit.

Comment: client.sendto((input("Voce: ")).encode('utf8') + ("\n").encode('‌​utf‌​8'),("192.168.1.7", 661)) -> worked!

Comment: Glad you got it working man :) Even set a reminder in my phone to remind me to post this this morning for you. Good luck!